# failed deployment in railways for react application with node backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, railway

"I want to deploy my full-stack application on Railway. To do that, do I need to create a command similar to 'heroku-postbuild' in Railway? In Heroku, the 'heroku-postbuild' script is used to specify additional commands that should run after the regular build process. I'm wondering if Railway has a similar feature or if I need to set up a custom command to handle the build process for both the frontend and backend of my application."[this is my package.json scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgpN9.png)[this is index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrXj9.png) My react code is present in client direcory[these are my directory's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8woeR.png)

I want to know how to deploy node appliaction with react as frontend in railway